# Removing image from array in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a webshop based in Woocommerce.
In the single product page, I removed the Featured image (by deleting the code that calls it), and replaced it by the first image from the gallery in big size, using the following code:

```
<?php
  $imgid = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
?>

<a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imgid[0] ); ?>" 
   class="woocommerce-main-image zoom first" 
   rel="lightbox[product-gallery]">
        <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $imgid[0] ); ?>" alt="">   
</a>
```

Right after that, the thumbnails are called:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' ); ?>
```

As the first image from the array is already displayed in big size, I've managed to remove it from the thumbnails list like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery('.thumbnails.columns-3 a:first-child').hide()
</script>
```

My only problem now, is that the first image will still appear twice in the Lightbox, as it is still present in the gallery 2 times.

How could I remove it from the array from the Lightbox but not from the array from the gallery?

I've tried the following but is giving me errors:

```
// define the woocommerce_product_thumbnails callback
function action_woocommerce_product_thumbnails(        $woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails, $number ) 
{
    $array = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    $size = count($array);
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i += 2) {
      $result[] = $array[$i];
    }
    var_dump($result);
}

// add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails',    'action_woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 10, 2 );

// add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'action_woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 10, 2 );
```

Any tips on what to try next?

Comment: You can filter [`woocommerce_product_gallery_attachment_ids`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L153). Though I'm curious why you don't just set one image as the featured image and save yourself this hassle.

Comment: @helgatheviking It's a format problem, I want all product images to have the same format in the shop grid, but once in single product page, this cropped pic is irrelevant... How could I filter the ids as you say?

Comment: Ok, now it makes more sense. What about using [Multiple Post Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/)? You could set a loop thumbnail (your cropped image) and then a second image for the product page.

Comment: @helgatheviking it took me a while but I managed to rephrase the question. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835142/duplicated-pic-in-thumbnail-gallery-in-woocommerce) . Any tip on how to do it without plugin (I try to stay away from them as much as possible for long term security issues) and taking into account the work already done?

Many thanks for the input!!

Comment: I think it would have been better to edit this question. Now you've created a duplicate and I'm not sure where to post my answer. Though the rephrasing makes it clearer that you should use Multiple Post Thumbnails: that is exactly its purpose, but I've come up with a custom template alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't solve the exact question here (two solutions are provided at the improved version of the question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31840075/383847)), but for future reference here is an example of how to filter `woocommerce_product_gallery_attachment_ids`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_attachment_ids', 'so_31818331_filter_gallery', 10, 2 );
function so_31818331_filter_gallery( $ids, $product ){
    // remove image attachment id=99 from all galleries
    if( in_array( 99, $ids ) ){
        unset( $ids['99'] );
    }
    return $ids;
}
```